# I have a car drive-train question.

Tags: drivetrain

I have a car drive train question. I'm looking at used SUVs since my last car died 3 months ago (20 yr old Honda Accord), specifically looking at vehicles like the Honda CR-V or Toyota RAV4.I know AWD and 4WD = All Wheel Drive and 4 Wheel Drive but is 2WD the same as FWD (which I know is Front Wheel Drive)?

I ask this because out of all 4, I'm trying to figure out which drive train is the best for me because I want something I can drive in different terrains, not just city and highway, but maybe in more rough/rocky areas.

I do more camping sometime, I also drive on the snow(I know chains too. It snows in the winter where my sister is and never been in wintertime but I might do that next year). So out of those 4, which is the best for me? Or maybe the best 2 out of all those? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your use I would suggest a 4WD or AWD since power to all 4 wheels will increase traction and generally better for off-Roading,

2WD is when either the front two wheels (FWD) or the Rear two wheels (RWD) are driven at any point of time.

RWD are slightly better for climbing or incline type of surface , FWD is better for slippery surface.

other things which you might consider:

- AWD/4WD are best for off Roading.
- FWD are cheaper to buy and maintain.
- FWD dont have a central hump in the middle of the back seats(more legroom)
- RWD provide better performance figures.

Update:

- 4WD is more ecnonomical to run and cheaper to buy than AWD.
- 4WD is better at Off-Roading than AWD(keep in mind AWD is better than RWD or FWD)
- AWD is better for Snowy conditions and increased traction(on the ROAD).
- AWD is much more sharp and sportier around the corners.

> If you are going to do partial off roading it would be better to go
>   for AWD compared to 4WD since the computers in AWD will determing the
>   required traction needs at the current moment compared to the 4WD
>   where you will need to flip a switch manually.

*(Thanks to Paulster2 for the additional info)*